# Segmentation fault when programming Quicksort in C++

Tags: c++, quicksort

I'm trying to program the first algorithm on [this page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort) in C++. This is what I get when I adapt this to this language:

```
void quicksort (vector<int>& numbers) {
      int leftSize = numbers.size() / 3
      , rightSize = numbers.size() - leftSize;
      vector<int>::iterator pivot = numbers.end() - rightSize; //Choose one third of the way through as the pivot.
      vector<int> left;
      vector<int> right;

      if(numbers.size() <= 1) {
          return;
      }

      //Place numbers less than the pivot on the left side and numbers greater on the right side
      for(vector<int>::iterator x = numbers.begin(); x < numbers.end(); x++) {
          if(*x < *pivot) {
              left.push_back(*x);
          } else {
              right.push_back(*x);
          }
      }

      quicksort(left);
      quicksort(right);

      //Concatenate the arrays
      numbers.clear();
      numbers.insert(numbers.end(), left.begin(), left.end());
      numbers.insert(numbers.end(), right.begin(), right.end());
}
```

But this is giving an error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I'm only testing this on a vector of size 20, so it shouldn't be that I'm running out of memory. What I've been able to find out is that it's the call to `quicksort(right)` that's causing the problem. Commenting out only that line and leaving `quicksort(left)` produces no runtime errors (although the vector obviously doesn't come out sorted).

Any ideas why `quicksort(left)` would work, but not `quicksort(right)`?

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to sound like I was asking people to spot errors in my code. I wouldn't have posted this if I hadn't gone over it and compared it to the pseudo-code that I posted on the other site line for line, to make sure they were the same. That's why I'm posting this, because I'm literally out of ideas for what could be wrong, when it's basically a line-for-line implementation of the other code, just in C++  (except for the equal array, I forgot to implement that but didn't think it would be causing this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose the minimum element of a vector as a pivot, then all elements (including the pivot) will go into `right`. You then call `quicksort` on `right`, which is the same vector you had before. Each call to `quicksort` makes an identical call to `quicksort`, you quickly exceed the maximum depth of the stack and get a segfault.

Comment: Thanks. I printed out the numbers and the pivot and it seems that is what's happening, although I don't understand why it's always choosing the smallest number for the pivot. The numbers are randomly-generated, and the pivot is always set to a third of the way through the vector, so it shouldn't always be the smallest number.

Comment: @user2242700: This is one reason why many implementations choose the pivot element at random — it minimizes the chance of running into a bad pivot on every recursion.

Comment: @user2242700: *Think it through.* If you start with a randomly generated vector of length 20, what is the probability that it will not pick the minimum as the pivot *in any of the calls?*